# adb starts but won't respond

Tags: android, eclipse, adb

I'm using eclipse and, sometimes, adb directly.  Either way, the adb server starts but neither eclipse nor the adb command app can make a connection.  Eclipse gives error:
   The connection to adb is down... you must restart... 
I try the connection from eclipse by attempting to debug my app; from the command line I try adb logcat.

This problem had been intermittent over the last week or so, ever since I updated the android sdk tools and platform tools.  I just updated again to 21.0.1 and 16, respectively.  Now the problem is 100% consistent and I cannot debug any code :(

I'm running eclipse and adb on Window 7.  I'm trying to connect to a Nexus 7 or a Kyocera CS170.

I've tried using Task Manager to kill adb.  If either device is plugged in, adb restarts automatically, but still doesn't connect.  If not plugged in, I can start it via the adb command line.  Then, after plugging in a device, it still doesn't connect.

Any idea?

Comment: just discovered that there is a version 16.1 which had failed to install.  I just retried that and got it to install.  adb seems to be working now, but I'm going to give some time before marking this question fixed.

Comment: Still not working.  I can get adb on the command line connecting to the server (after several tries).  Not in eclipse, though.  I've tried about 20 times, various combinations of actions.  No one else is having this problme?

Comment: Found other forums and posts talking about this: the problem happens because the SDK has a newer verson of adb than some app communicating with the device - often a calendar or contact sync program.  That was my case.  I made progress by temporarily renaming the adb in the other app so that it couldn't launch. Now I'm able to start Eclipse and connect to the device.  Yea!  But, funny, if I start adb on the command line first, Eclipse fails.  Still want to understand more before posting a solution here.